# How to use my webcam as emulator camera on android studio ? Windows 11

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, webcam

[I have set the front and back camera as webcam0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67n9s.png)

I have set the front and back camera as webcam0 but when i open 'camera' apps in the emulator it force close and give me this error message,

Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CameraActivity}

[i tried to troubleshoot device connection and here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21D5Q.png)

i have delete the webcam driver and restart my pc, and also update the driver, and i have activated the USB debugging in emulator too. but in the end still same the problem not solved.